# Usuario DB Oracle Bloqueado. multiples bases

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g, sqlplus

Buen Día.

Presento el siguiente inconveniente... Tengo instalado Oracle11gXE en un servidor. Por default oracle crea una base de datos llamada `XE` y en la implementación se creo la base de datos `Emp1`con un único usuario `User1`.
este usuario mencionado se bloqueo por cantidad de intentos de sesión y hasta el momento no lo he podido desbloquear.

lo primero que intente fue iniciar con sysdba y realizar un alter user así:

```
C:\Users\Administrator>sqlplus / as sysdba

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.2.0 Production on Fri Apr 9 23:50:30 2021

Copyright (c) 1982, 2010, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - Production

SQL> alter user Emp1 account unlock;
alter user Emp1 account unlock
           *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01918: user 'Emp1' does not exist
```

Esto sucede porque el usuario sysdba esta anclado a la base por default XE

```
SQL> SELECT NAME FROM v$database;

NAME
---------
XE
```

Ya lo intente con el usuario `system` y arroja el mismo resultado. De que modo podría desbloquear el usuario siendo este el unico creado bajo la bd `Emp1`?

Estoy realizando el proceso en sqlplus directamente en el servidor conectada por RDP

De antemano mil gracias por su ayuda :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No es que el usuario `sysdba` esté *anclado* a una instancia particular, sino que el sqlplus, de esta manera, se conectará a la *instancia por defecto* del equipo, que es la `XE`.

Para que se conecte a otra instancia, cambia el valor de la [variable de entorno](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADMQS/GUID-EC18C4A6-3BA5-4C14-9D76-B0DD62FEFFF2.htm#ADMQS12369) `ORACLE_SID`, de `XE`, en este caso a `Emp1`, y ya con eso el sqlplus debiera conectarse a esa instancia.

En Windows, puedes valerte del **Oracle Administration Assistant for Windows** para realizar el cambio.

Luego de eso ejecuta el comando, que debiera conectarse a la instancia `Emp1` en lugar de a `XE`

```
sqlplus / as sysdba
```

Comment: me has salvado la vida! No te imaginas cuanto tiempo llevo tratando de solucionar ese inconveniente y el ningún lado encontré información útil. Ya pude realizar el desbloqueo de usuario y pude recuperar el acceso a mi BD. Muchas gracias!!!

Comment: Es un gusto ser de ayuda. Un saludo.